# Windows File Server Directory Statistics on Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

currently at work we are onboarding to Prometheus, to replace some custom made (& high maintenance ) monitoring tools for:

- File size in a directory
- Count of files in a directory
- Age of files in a directory

So in order to really replace the tool with similar functionalities sending it to Prometheus. I have searched the internet far and wide, but could not find any already existing Exporter for Windows that does this.... I came accross the standard windows_exporter(https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter), but it doesnt seem to have the functionalities.

Does anyone know of something like this is availble for windows? I know for Unix the node_exporter provides these statistics.

If something like this is not available, then I would see very little other alternatives then writing an own exporter. I read that (most) are written in Golang, something I have never worked with. Any suggestions?